# Export | Import DynamoDB only with AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli

My goal is to have simple tool for export dynamodb to local file(json/csv) only with `aws cli` or less 3th party as it's possible. The size of my tables are around 500mb.

I'm doing the research for few days now and I saw very nice projects like `dynamodump` and another SDK implementations. Also I test the `Datapipeline` from Amazon, but for task that I'm targeting want simple `aws cli`.

Let's say that I already have map for the table such as indexs and attributes.Now I want to import just the Items that I have. For me the best solution for the implementation that I have will be something like this:

1. Exporting the table from aws to local file:
   `aws dynamodb scan --table-name SOMETABLENAME  --output json |  jq '.Items[]' > SOMETABLENAME.json`
2. Rendering the file with things like `sed`, `jq`, `awk` ...etc. To get proper json format whom can be imported to aws-dynamodb
3. Import the Items from SOMETABLENAME to aws-dynamodb with:

   `aws dynamodb put-item --table-name SOMETABLENAME --item file://SOMETABLENAME.json`

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. It looks like you already figured out the command line to export a table using the AWS CLI (using `aws dynamodb scan`) as well as for imports, using `aws dynamodb put-item`. Are you just looking for confirmation?

Comment: only AWS-Cli is not going to help you here because scan will return the json with limited records so is you want to export entire table then you need create script which iterates and store data in local files

Comment: Might be useful: https://github.com/tachikoma-ai/dynamodb-migration-script

Answer (score 19):

You can export the data using aws dynamodb scan.

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name table_name --region aws_region_name --max-items max_items --output json > ./export.json
```

However, DynamoDB has a 1MB limit on the amount of data it will retrieve in a single request. If you hit the 1MB limit with a Scan, it will return a "NextToken" key in the response.

You need to scan it again with NextToken, until all the data have been exported.

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name table_name --region aws_region_name --max-items max_items --starting-token nextToken --output json > ./export2.json
```

Regarding the import, BatchWriteItem can write up to 16 MB or 25 put or delete requests. You can set the max_items to 25 or split it using jq.

You can convert the json to BatchWriteItem cli via jq.

```
cat filepath | jq "{\"table_name\": [.Items[] | {PutRequest: {Item: .}}]}" > BatchWriteItem.txt
```

Finally, you can insert the to dynamodb using cmd.

```
aws dynamodb batch-write-item --request-items file://filepath
```

It's better to do with shell script if the data is huge.
More details:
https://github.com/mickey2012ex/dynamodb-data-migrator

The best solution is AWS Data Pipeline, if the region is supported

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28905348)

Comment: Updated the essential parts of the script.
 Thanks for the reminder

Comment: this did not work for me :(

Comment: I suspect there's a small typo in the `jq` query.
Replacing `.[]` with `.Items[]` got this working for me.

Answer (score 4):

If it's a small table you can use this (this is clearly an example so you have to change the region and of course create the access key and secret

```
#backup command
aws --region us-west-2  dynamodb scan --table-name YOUR_TABLE_NAME --no-paginate > data.json

# login to aws console and create the new NEW_YOUR_TABLE_NAME

# lastly, load it 
cat data.json | jq -c '.Items[]' | while read -r line; do aws --region us-west-2  dynamodb put-item --table-name NEW_YOUR_TABLE_NAME --item "$line"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

DynamoDB released a new feature to export your data to an S3 bucket. It's a native, server-less solution that can be used via the CLI, as you desire - see:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/export-table-to-point-in-time.html

That will help you achieve #1 without the intermediate scan, but unfortunately, as of Nov 2020, there's no native import functionality to get it to a new table.

If all you're interested in is getting the data from one table to another, you can use PiTR:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/restore-table-to-point-in-time.html